# use select result as column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a temp table with values inside

```
select distinct sub from #t
```

which gives me values

```
1-aaa
2-bbb
3-ccc
....
so on
```

and then I'm doing the following

```
select fullname,
  max(case when sub='aaa' then score end) 'aaa',
  max(case when sub='bbb' then score end) 'bbb',
  max(case when sub='ccc' then score end) 'ccc'
from #t
group by fullname
```

and this gives a result of

```
fullname - aaa - bbb - ccc

fn1 - 15 - 18 - 21
fn2 - 18 - 23 - 33
fn3 - xx - yy - zz
```

the thing is that #t might contain up to 100's of "names"

here's what I can't do

is there a way to change the part

```
max(case when sub='aaa' then score end) 'aaa'
```

with for/each like loop based on valeus from #t?

thanks

Comment: If you need the columns to be dynamic, you need the SQL to also be dynamic. If all the columns are known, then you'll need to script them all out. Personally, however, I feel things like dynamic pivots are better done in your presentation layer. For example SSRS Matrixes are great for this, as are Pivot Tables in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking, however, on Dynamic SQL, here is a solution that does do this dynamically for you:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (FullName varchar(15),
                 sub char(3),
                 score int);
INSERT INTO #T
VALUES ('Joe Bloggs','aaa',17),
       ('Joe Bloggs','bbb',9),
       ('Joe Bloggs','ccc',24),
       ('Joe Bloggs','eee',14),
       ('Joe Bloggs','fff',12),
       ('Jane Smith','aaa',2),
       ('Jane Smith','ccc',12),
       ('Jane Smith','ddd',15),
       ('Jane Smith','eee',19),
       ('Jane Smith','ggg',21);

GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT Fullname,' + NCHAR(10) + STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT N',' + NCHAR(10) + N'MAX(CASE sub WHEN ''' + REPLACE(sub,N'''',N'''''') + N''' THEN score END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(sub) + N''
                                       FROM #T
                                       FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,2,N'') + '
FROM #T
GROUP BY Fullname;';

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
DROP TABLE #t;
```

If you don't understand this, please do ask.

Comment: thanks, after seeing your comment I immediately "went out" seeing dynamic Sql :) and found out something similar that made me accomplish whatever I was doing :D , so ty again.